# Discord.py how to make role reactions?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My situation is the following: I have a message on a discord server which has a reaction emoji and I want the users who react with that emoji to receive a role.

However, it does not seem to produce any kind of effect when users react to the emoji, I have been trying different things, but have not achieved the desired effect at any time.

My code is:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_reaction_add(self,reaction):
        role = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.channel.guild.roles, id=820934815217221671)
        if reaction.message_id == 820972326878969866:
            if reaction.emoji == "✅":
                reaction.author.add_roles(role)
```

However nothing happens, I have also tried with **on_raw_reaction_add** with payload argument but this make a error saying:
TypeError: on_raw_reaction_add() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

What is wrong with my logic? I've been looking at different examples and can't come to a conclusion.

Comment: There are at least 4 errors I can see right away. Answering your question "what's wrong with my logic", pretty much everything, you didn't even take a look at the docs, there are too many wrong things with this code, also I believe that this is not the code you're using. Please edit your question and clear up some things, otherwise we won't be able to help

Answer (score 0):

Based on **Łukasz Kwieciński's** comment, here is a possible answer.
You need other "values" for the event. It is not `reaction`, but `payload`, see the docs: [on_raw_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction#discord.on_raw_reaction_add).

Then you also have to define a channel or at least the correct message ID first, you do that like this:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload): # added payload
    guild = self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    member = get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
    # channel and message IDs should be integer:
    if payload.channel_id == ChannelID and payload.message_id == messageID:
```

Next you need to include `payload.emoji` and paste it in the typical format, as an example:

```py
if str(payload.emoji) == "YourEmoji": # Make sure it is a string
    role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, name='NameOfTheRole') # ID is also possible
```

If the role exists we have to add it of course, we do that with:

```py
if role is not None:
    await payload.member.add_roles(role)
```

Of course, since this is just an example, there are still a few things that need to be built in, but this would be the approximate shell of the event.

***For more information also look at the following in the docs: [RawReactionActionEvent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent)***